# Django test discovery does not find non django test cases

Tags: python, django, python-unittest

I have am building an application that involves and some non-django functionality.
I have an app 'wit' under the source  directory that is a django application and that has test cases that are being deferred.

```
src/wit/   test_django_file1.py, test_django_file2.py etc.
```

But there are also test cases under that are not being discovered or run

```
src/utils/ test_nondjango1.py and test_nondjango2.py
```

src/utils is not a django application in the installed apps list

When I run do

```
cd src/
python manage.py test
```

The tests under src/utils are not being discovered or run

I am using django jenkins report coverage to get coverage reports.
I would idealy like all the test cases to be invoked with one invocation so that over all code coverage reporting works.

Or else I would like to know how to invoke separately if the above is not possibly so that I get to run all my test cases anyway.

How do I debug this, and figure out which directories are being explored.

Answer (score 1):

#### Debugging

Is your utils dir a valid python package (has an `__init__.py`?).
And, are the modules under it importable? E.g can you do the following:

```
cd root_dir/
python -c "from src.utils import test_nondjango1"
```

If the above raises an `ImportError`, making it importable is one way you can make the tests "discoverable". Another way would be to specify the directory explicitly when running the tests:

```
python manage.py tests src.wit src/utils/
```

This provides two labels to the [test runner](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests): `src.wit` which a full Python dotted path and `src/utils/` which is a relative directory.

#### Explanation

[Django docs state] that it "unittest module’s [built-in test discovery](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery)". The first paragraphs in the linked docs say:

> Unittest supports simple test discovery. In order to be compatible
>   with test discovery, all of the test files must be modules or packages
>   (including namespace packages) importable from the top-level directory
>   of the project (this means that their filenames must be valid
>   identifiers).
>
> Test discovery is implemented in TestLoader.discover(), but can also
>   be used from the command line...

Just to clarify further, the [`discover()` method docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.discover) says:

> **discover**(start_dir, pattern='test*.py', top_level_dir=None)
>
> Find all the test modules by recursing into subdirectories from the
>   specified start directory, and return a TestSuite object containing
>   them. Only test files that match pattern will be loaded. (Using shell
>   style pattern matching.) Only module names that are importable (i.e.
>   are valid Python identifiers) will be loaded.
>
> All test modules must be importable from the top level of the project.
>   If the start directory is not the top level directory then the top
>   level directory must be specified separately.
>
> If importing a module fails, for example due to a syntax error, then
>   this will be recorded as a single error and discovery will continue.
>   If the import failure is due to SkipTest being raised, it will be
>   recorded as a skip instead of an error.